# Understanding quantum field theory via simulation

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, computational-physics, education

I took graduate QFT course 10 years ago as an undergrad. Did all the homework assignments but it never quite stuck.

I think I'd understand the subject better if it were presented differently; focusing on **how to write a numerical simulation**, rather than how to do symbolic manipulations.

For studying finite-dimensional quantum systems like a singlle particle, this is easy: the Hamiltonian just defines a PDE, which can easily be simulated. But for QFT, my understanding is that there's something similar going on, but there's an infinite-dimensional state at each point.

Googling keywords led me to this paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1811.10085 which I'd like to understand, but I got lost quickly once Preskill got into the meat of the explanation " More informally, a scalar field φ(x) is an unbounded quantum continuous variable at each point x in space."

Can someone advise me on what to read next to understand how to simulate QFT?

Comment: I'd look into lattice field theories, this a main approach for numerical quantum field theory.

Comment: Lattice field theory is the main approach for non-perturbative field theory, but OP may also want to look into perturbative computations of, for example, scattering amplitudes.